# Sharing global variable between two processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run two `while` loops concurrently in two separate processes, where the first one modifies a global variable, based on which the other process takes a decision.

My problem is, the global variable isn't modified before the first process finishes, so the second process doesn't properly respond to it.

This is my code:

```
flag = [False]
def loop1():  
  x = 0
  while (x<10):
    x = x + 1
    read = input("Enter 0 or 1")
    if read == 0:
      flag[0] = False
    else:
      flag[0] = True
def loop2():
  z = 0
  while (z<100):
    z = z + 1
    if flag[0] == False:
      # do something
    else:
      # do other thing
    time.sleep(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  Process(target = loop1).start()
  Process(target = loop2).start()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes do not share state. You will need to use a shared queue like from `multiprocessing.Queue`, give the queue object to both processes as an argument and pass the flag variable around via the queue.

Alternatively use `threading` instead of `multiprocessing` and threads which share a process's address space and can use the same (reference to a) variable.

There are pros and cons to both approaches, make a search on threading vs multiprocessing on SO for references.

In the threading case, the flag object will need to be bound to an object containing all spawned threads that are to use it, for example in a class:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from threading import Thread
import time


class State(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = False
        self.consumer_thread = Thread(target=self.check_flag)
        self.consumer_thread.daemon = True
        self.consumer_thread.start()

    def read_input(self):
        while True:
            _read = input()
            if _read == 0:
                self.flag = False
            else:
                self.flag = True
            time.sleep(1)

    def check_flag(self):
         while True:
            if self.flag is True:
                print("Is true")
                # do stuff
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    state = State()
    state.read_input()
```

Both threads (main thread + consumer thread) refer to the same object, `self.flag` and share the `self`, ie the class object's, address space.

Comment: Why not `multiprocessing.Value`? I should mention that as long as the program is not CPU bound, then using threads is preferred (implementation wise). But when it is CPU bounded, then you'll have to use processes rather than threads.

Comment: Can use that but will have to convert from integer to bool - `Value` does not take boolean types. And that is an over simplification, it depends. If what is being run in the thread is _not_ python code, ie a native extension or third party library with native code, then threads will always be preferred, CPU bound or no. Multiple processes allow CPU bound python code to be run in parallel as each process will have its own GIL.